# XAMPP tmp folder oversized

Tags: php, apache, logging, xampp, xdebug

I'm running some php file every 2 minutes via Windows Task Scheduler, but time-to-time I get notification about low space on my drive `D:`.

After check I found that in XAMPP `tmp` folder located on `D:\XAMPP\tmp` are lot of files with names similar to: `cachegrind.out.1381478803-D__xampp_htdocs_Real_Estate_App_index_php` and size of each file is more than 144 MB.

These files have content:

```
==== NEW PROFILING FILE ==============================================
version: 1
creator: xdebug 2.2.3
cmd: D:\xampp\htdocs\Real Estate App\index.php
part: 1
positions: line

events: Time

fl=php:internal
fn=php::header
3 0

fl=php:internal
fn=php::define
45 0

...
```

I understand that this is caused because of xdebug, but how to stop this process I don't know.
Mybe someone had same problem? Any ideas?

Answer (score 50, accepted):

You have xdebug profiling enabled. If this is enabled xdebug will write runtime information about the scripts into systems temp folder (by default). Disable it in your php.ini (or in the xdebug.ini, depends on where did you set it)

```
xdebug.profiler_enable=Off
```

and restart the web server

Comment: I found [XDebug] category in my php.ini file with option: `xdebug.profiler_enable = 1`. I switched value to 0 and looks like my problem is solved. Thanks a lot!

Comment: you are welcome. you can delete the existing cachegrind files as well

Comment: can we delete those files in tmp folder it is really taking lot of space ?? @hek2mgl

Comment: @hek2mgl :     xdebug.profiler_enable = 0 | is zero in my php.ini but still i see tmp folder oversized, what are other things which might have caused this ?

Comment: @hitesh have you restarted the webserver?

Comment: @hek2mgl   no i didnt change the value, In php.ini the value was zero initially...since i didnt change it, i dont need to restart the browser, I wanted to know what are other things which might cause this  issue other than xdebug

Comment: @hitesh There are a 1000s of reasons possible. You need to check which files are in /tmp and who is creating that files.

Comment: @hek2mgl  : I have files of size 160 mb just now created when i started using my drupal site of name cachegrind.out.1393565671-H__xampp_htdocs_gemkt_trunk_index_php ..... htdocs/gemkt/trunk/index.php these are folders...|| and there are lot of files getting created here of almost same size

Comment: Thank you, Ive just deleted 860GB of cachegrind.out files from my PC. its only a 920GB HDD. I wont be turning xdebug.profiler_enable back ON any time soon, unless there is a way of disabling the cache only ?

Answer (score 7):

Yes found out that turning xdebug.profiler to off does part of the trick

```
xdebug.profiler_enable= 0
```

Then also turn off also eAccelerator which precomplies codes

; The directory that is used for disk cache. eAccelerator stores precompiled
; code, session data, content and user entries  here. The same data can be
; stored in shared memory also (for more quick access).

```
eaccelerator.enable="0"
```

**Then stop apache**

**Delete the files** in the *tmp dir*

**Resart apache** does the trick