# XAMPP tmp folder oversized and shows MySQL high CPU usage

Tags: php, mariadb, xampp, diskspace, tmp

I am running a PHP application on XAMPP (PHP 7.3) which my users are usually uploading files (Image and PDF) and the activities on the application are increasing day by day. But Recently I am facing low space on my drive and it shows MySQL high CPU usage up to 97%.

Then I found that in XAMPP, tmp folder ('C:\XAMPP\tmp') there are files with name mysql[random number] with .MAD extension that size of each file is more than 35 GB, and it continue to generate these files until the disk become full and application stop working.

*Then I need to stop the XAMPP service and delete the files that the system back to normal.*

There are solutions similar to this issue such as [XAMPP tmp folder oversized](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19313422/xampp-tmp-folder-oversized) and it recommended to disable xdebug profile in php.ini or xdebug.ini which I couldn't found it in PHP 7.3 version but I added at the end of php.ini like below and checked the php_xdebug.dll is available in php extension folder...

```
[XDebug] 
xdebug.remote_autostart=0
xdebug.remote_enable=0
xdebug.profiler_enable=0
```

... and [How can I limit the size of temporary tables?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43611304/how-can-i-limit-the-size-of-temporary-tables) which the answers was not to the point even though I followed the answers and implemented some points but still the application is facing the same problem.

Now, I am looking for step by step solution to avoid or to understand what is reason that I could solve the problem.

Comment: You might want to look at other questions like https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43611304/how-can-i-limit-the-size-of-temporary-tables

Comment: @Milad-Mehraban  Do you still need assistance with this issue?

Comment: @WilsonHauck Yes, I have implemented the below answer which I verified and it worked fine at the first time but I faced the same problem again and the tmp folder size increased again.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

- in `my.ini` make sure value of `max_heap_table_size` and `tmp_table_size` is not too high.
- as you mentioned in your question, make sure `xdebug.profiler_enable` is set to `Off` in `php.ini`. if doesnt exist just add it.
- make sure you optimize your database tables regularly.
- remove unneccesary indexes. index columns you use to query.
- run queries one by one and check which query is making the huge files.
- if didnt work try using `innodb` instead of `MyISAM`.